# GAS OR operator makes both tests ignored

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, or-operator

I have this function looping through all sheets, and if the sheet is not hidden, add the sheet name to the array `out`.

```
function sheetnames() {

  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();

  var out = new Array()
  for (var i=0 ; i<sheets.length ; i++) 
    if (sheets[i].isSheetHidden()!= true){
      out.push( [ sheets[i].getName() ] 
            )}
  Logger.log(out);
}
```

I would also like to test for specific sheet names, which I am able to do with

```
if (sheets[i].getSheetName()!= 'Sheet1'){
```

However when I put them together with `||` an OR operator, both tests are ignored.

```
if (sheets[i].isSheetHidden()!= true || sheets[i].getSheetName()!= 'Sheet1'){
```

I'm not sure if it is the way I am handling `||` or something else I'm not seeing.

In this example, sheet1 is visible, so would pass the first part of the test.

Comment: When you say "ignored", what do you mean?

Comment: That shouldn't happen - the code you have should work just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(sheets[i].isSheetHidden()!= true || sheets[i].getSheetName()!= 'Sheet1')
```

will return `true` if the current sheet is not hidden or not named 'Sheet1'. Or in other words, it will *only return* `true` *if the current sheet is named 'Sheet1' **and** is hidden*. That's probably not what you want, is it? Perhaps what you're looking for is the `&&` AND logical operator?

Also, I'd suggest you look into formatting code, why you should use `!==` instead of `!=`, and see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931872/what-s-the-difference-between-array-and-while-declaring-a-javascript-ar) for information on using `var a = [];` compared to `var b = new Array();`