# Javascript: How to compare two arrays, and return the name of the array with highest value in a certain index

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have been working on the scoring system for a game I am building with Javascript and have run into a problem. I am trying to compare the index 0 of a couple of arrays and return the index 1 of the array with the highest value.

This is what I have so far:

```
var player1 = new Array [1, "billy"];
var player2 = new Array [2, "jean"];

function checkWinner() {
    var winner = Math.max(player1[0], player2[0]);
    console.log(winner[1]);
}

checkWinner();
```

Comment: You can't use `new Array []` to instantiate arrays. Use `new Array()` or `[]`. [Here's the difference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/931872/8289918).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bonus: check the winner of any number of players:

```js
var player1 = [1, "billy"];
var player2 = [2, "jean"];

function checkWinner() {
    var players = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    var max = Math.max.apply(null, players.map(function (p) {
        return p[0];
    }));
    var winner = players.filter(function (p) {
        return p[0] === max;
    })[0];
    console.log(winner[1]);
}

checkWinner(player1, player2);
```

ES2015:

```js
const player1 = [1, "billy"];
const player2 = [2, "jean"];

const checkWinner = (...players) => {
    const max = Math.max(...players.map(p => p[0]));
    const winner = players.find(p => p[0] === max);
    console.log(winner[1]);
}

checkWinner(player1, player2);
```

Answer (score 1):

I really like [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) as an option here. It goes through each of the players 1 by 1 and if the current player has a higher score than the previous player, then the current player has the highest score (and at the end will be the winner).

```
const players = [
  {
    name: "billy",
    score: 3
  },
  {
    name: "jean",
    score: 2
  }
];

const getWinner = players => players.reduce((currentWinner, player) => 
  player.score > currentWinner.score ? player : currentWinner
)
const winner = getWinner(players)
console.log(`The winner is: ${winner.name}!`)
```

I also changed the array of (score, name) to be an object with keys "score" and "name" to be able to reference those values later with out brackets.

Comment: I think you meant `currentWinner` instead of `acc` in `player.score > currentWinner.score ? player : acc`.

Comment: thank you for pointing this out! I have edited the above answer

Answer (score 0):

In your code the variable `winner` will be an integer that is the larger of the 2 scores. It's not an array that you can get index 1 from. You want to get the player Array that has the higher score, not the score itself. You can do that like this:

```
function checkWinner() {
    var winner = player1;
    if (player1[0] < player2[0]) {
        winner = player2;
    }
    console.log(winner[1]);
}
```

This doesn't handle the case where there is a tie, but you can add an if-statement for that also.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a simple if:

```
function checkWinner() {
var winner;
if (player1[0] < player2[0]) {
    winner = player2;
}else{
    winner = player1;
}

console.log(winner[1]);
```

}