# Difference splicing between Array() and [] in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, insert, splice

I am trying to replicate Python's insert at index functionality in Javascript.

```
var index = [0,1,2,3,4]
var nums = [0,1,2,2,1]

const target = new Array(nums.length);

for (let i=0; i<index.length; i++) {
  target.splice(nums[i], 0, index[i]);
};

console.log(target);
```

This produces the following output:

> [ 0, 4, 1, 3, 2, <5 empty items> ]

However, if I run the following code:

```
var index = [0,1,2,3,4]
var nums = [0,1,2,2,1]

const target = [] //new Array(nums.length);

for (let i=0; i<index.length; i++) {
  target.splice(nums[i], 0, index[i]);
};

console.log(target);
```

This produces the following output:

> [ 0, 4, 1, 3, 2 ]

What is going on? The second output is the one I desire.

Comment: Please take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/931875/1376618)

Answer (score 0):

`new Array(nums.length)` will fill the array with 'empty slots' for that number.

`const target = []` Will be [ ]

`const target = new Array(5)` will be [, , , , ]

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Array More info here.

Answer (score 0):

when you initialize array like this :

```
const target = new Array(index.length);
```

This code will initiate "target" array with five empty box. in result it contain garbage value and it may affect your value after insertion.

But when you initialize like this :

```
const target = [];
```

This code will initiate  "target" array without defining the size of it. 
 it means you can insert n number of dynamic value inside this. 
 
('n' denote the size of array)

So always use second option which is good practice to use javascript Array