# Object.keys(data).map(v) not giving the actual key value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I want to convert an object into an array of object but my code give the wrong result like shown below..

```js
// object
data = { user_id : '123' }

// expected result
data = [ { user_id : '123' } ]

// what I get instead
data = [ { v : '123' } ]
```

my code:

```js
let arr = [];
Object.keys(data).map(v => {
  console.log(v, data[v]); // here it shows 'user_id' and '123' as it's supposed to
  arr.push({ v:data[v] }); // but here it uses the 'v' as property instead of 'user_id'
});
```

Comment: If you want to use computed values as keys you have to wrap them in `[]`. So you have `arr.push({ [v]: data[v] });`.

Comment: You can just wrap object in array :`data = [ data ]`

Comment: @A1exandrBelan is that the short way to typecast an object into array? like the same as `(array)$var1` in php?

Comment: @dapidmini It's not actually typecast, it's a short [syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/931872/87713) for getting a new array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put `v` inside a square bracket

```js
const data = {
  user_id: '123'
}

let arr = [];
Object.keys(data).map(v => {
  arr.push({
    [v]: data[v]
  });
});

console.log(arr)
```

Alternatively you can also use `Object.entries`. You dont need initialize `let arr = [];` as `map` will create a new array

```js
const data = {
  user_id: '123'
}
const arr = Object.entries(data).map(v => {
  return {
    [v[0]]: v[1]
  }
});

console.log(arr)
```

Comment: I know using `entries` will make the code shorter but I think I'll just `keys` instead because it's easier to read (at least for me).

Answer (score 0):

when you need to use variable as key in object, you must use [].

Example:

```
const key = 'user_id'
const obj = {
    [key]: 'user'
}

## result
{
'user_id': 'user
}
```

So change v to [v].

```
let arr = [];
Object.keys(data).map(v => {
  arr.push({ [v]:data[v] }); // replace v to [v] 
});
```

Comment: That answer has already been given. I recommend to delete it.