# Why would you create a new Array using an interface? (Pulumi)

Tags: arrays, typescript, interface, pulumi, infrastructure-as-code

Brand new to TypeScript and Pulumi/IaC. I'm trying to understand a piece of code where a bunch of key values are composed of a new array using an interface:

```
import * as cPulumi from "@company/pulumi";

interface TestInterface {
    name: cPulumi.output<string>,
    description: cPulumi.output<string>,
    password: cPulumi.output<string>
}

const allVm = {
    vm1: new Array<TestInterface>(),
    vm2: new Array<TestInterface>(),
    vm3: new Array<TestInterface>()
}

export { allVm }
```

Is this essentially creating an array for each "vm" where all the values in the index are shaped into TestInterface? I see a bit of code later that pushes multiple objects shaped like the interface into "vm1."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you answered your own question, it just creates an empty array, with defined item-type in the generics. The exact same code (assuming the Array constructor didn't [get overridden somehow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1273936/8507883)) could be written as:

```
const allVm = {
    vm1: [] as TestInterface[],
    vm2: [] as TestInterface[],
    vm3: [] as TestInterface[],
}
```

or as

```
const allVm: { vm1: TestInterface[], vm2: TestInterface[], vm3: TestInterface[] } = {
    vm1: [],
    vm2: [],
    vm3: [],
}
```

It's just that `new Array<Type>` is easier to read, also it is preferable in projects where type casting as in `[] as TestInterface[]` is banned by linter rules.

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoQM5gJLmvJZAbwChlzkQ4BbCALmSylAHMAaMigE0wWYAcwwAPYgGTVhwrJ%20cDBgDuwqF3FhmIFiQC%20JEglFZkcADYmAatWQBeYp3IA3agEYGICAuQBBKFDgBPAB50LFxIWEQIAD4ACgBKKQonACY3D29fAODMHDwIpFiE%202QnAGY0zx8-IJDc8IJo%20J09AxAjUwtqZJs7aSdXZABtAF1jDDQcsPxIkcTHLoYRsYnQvIbZ4rLF0bkVuumkDd19QzBjM0ty4hKXBlqp-IhZm9S9h-Xhthur%207WZ0e0PVIfVuQ0%20mwWYLm322HGOAHp4cgIG0AK5QFBgAAWcDO2Ig-mMGOQ%20MYNAgJBMEDOcAYYH8-Agwhg506PQ6lmSJDg7Iu1FKJCAA)