# jquery collect value of list items and place in array

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have the following HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li>List 1</li>
  <li>list 2</li>
  <li>list 3</li>
</ul>
```

Can I get the text content from the the `<li>`'s and place them in array using javascript?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

```
var arr = $("li").map(function() { return $(this).text() }).get();
```

- The [`map()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/map/) method creates a jQuery object populated with whatever is returned from the function (in this case, the text content of each `<li>` element).
- The [`get()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/get/) method (when passed no argument) converts that jQuery object into an actual Array.

Comment: What purpose does the `.get()` serve?

Comment: @Luke - I understand `.get()` returns the DOM element underneath the jquery, but what would the above code turn into without the `.get()`?

Comment: no it doesnt return the dom element, since we are not mapping a dom element. and btw, if there is no parameter in "get()" it returns the whole array. In this case, an array of the "text" value.

Comment: but the "get" is not requested, it just makes an basic array out of an jquery array. after mapping, you could use other jquery methods on it. Since the user with the question wants an array, we are giving him the basic array, without jquery

Comment: I knew there had to be a "nerd friendly" way to do this, this scratches my nerd itch +1

Answer (score 4):

```
var x = [];
$("ul li").each(function() {
  x.push($(this).text());
});
```

or simply:

```
var x = $.map($("ul li"), function( i ) { return $(i).text(); });
```