# Adding an input match-randomizer with JS / jQuery? V.2

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, random

I am trying to make a basic randomizer that can match things. Sort of like a date(Romance) picker, but different situation.

I want the product to look like this:

(User Input A1)

(User Input A2)

(User Input A3)

(User Input B1)

(User Input B2)

(User Input B3)

Where an A input randomly matches a B input, but A never matches an A, and A doesn't randomize.

So it looks like this:

A1 - (B#)

A2 - (B#)

A3 - (B#)

Problem is, I suck at JS. I take some classes on Codecademy, being HTML / CSS / jQuery. I keep trying different things, but they keep failing. Can someone help me?

---

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link class="jsbin"             href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js">                </script>
    <script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
</head>
<body>


<ul id="people"> People
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>  
</ul>
<hr />
<ul id="jobs"> Jobs
  <li><input></input></li>
  <li><input></input></li>
  <li><input></input></li>
  <li><input></input></li>
  <li><input></input></li>
  <li><input></input></li>
  <li><input></input></li>
  <li><input></input></li>
  <li><input></input></li>  
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

---

JS:

---

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#jobs').find('li').shuffle();
    var mynewlist = '';
    $('#people').find('li').each(function (index) {
        var jb = $('#jobs').find('li').eq(index);
        mynewlist += '<li>Person:' +  $(this).text() + ' Job:' + jb.text() + '</li>';
    });
    $(mynewlist).appendTo('#newList');
});
```

---

http://jsbin.com/ijotok/6/edit

This is what I have.

***I want the inputs to randomize, but it doesn't work.***

Comment: I would offer a bounty on this if I could xP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using some code from these posts:

- [jquery collect value of list items and place in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856283/jquery-collect-value-of-list-items-and-place-in-array)
- [How to randomize (shuffle) a JavaScript array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-a-javascript-array)

I updated your JSBin code with one possible implementation http://jsbin.com/ijotok/8/

Your present implementation has several issues with it, one of them being that you're executing the code as soon as the page loads, with nothing triggering the suffling once you have provided input values. Secondly `shuffle` is not built into jQuery (that's why you get `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'shuffle'`, which is why I added the `shuffleArray` function. You could add this as a jQuery plugin if you needed to (check out [this plugin](http://mktgdept.com/jquery-shuffle)). Third, you're accessing the content of the `<li>` with `.text()`, but you should be calling `.val()` on the inputs.

Take a look at my implementation and let me know if you have questions.