# An array of elements in jQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays

Markup code:

```
<div id="elements">
    <div>
        <a href="#">text</a>
        <a href="#">text</a>
        <a href="#">text</a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a href="#">text</a>
        <a href="#">text</a>
        <a href="#">text</a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a href="#">text</a>
        <a href="#">text</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please tell me how can I get an array of all elements of the `div`, so that later, it is possible to address an array of options?

Such as:

```
divs[0]  
links[1]
```

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/247023/844726

Quite a few options.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/mWaRf/)

```
var divs = $('#elements div');
var links = $('#elements div a');
```

1. If you want the DOM elements, then you can access them with the array style like `divs[0]` or `links[2]`.
2. If you want to get the specific jQuery object, you can access them with `divs.eq(0)` or `links.eq(1)`.

Comment: I get an array of links for each div separately?    
$ ('# elements div [0] a');    
like - something like that, just to correct it. )    
I need to do the sorting. :)

Comment: @SirRoland Yes, you can do `$('#elements div:eq(0) a');`.

Comment: if I write:  var links=$('#elements div:eq(0) a').length;
        alert(links); // = 0

Answer (score 16):

See https://api.jquery.com/toArray/

```
$( "li" ).toArray()
```

This works great in cases like

```
$( "li" ).toArray().each( function(li) {
  console.log('do something with this list item', li);
})
```

or if you really want

```
$( "li" ).toArray()[0]
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. The accepted answer is outdated.

Answer (score 8):

```
$('#elements div').eq(0) // first div

$('#elements div a').eq(1) // second anchor in group of divs
```

Without the `.eq()` you have a collection of elements, the `.eq` just singles the elements out.

Answer (score 1):

```
wrapper = document.getElementById('elements');
divs = wrapper.getElementsByTagName('div');
links = [];
for (i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    links[i] = divs[i].getElementsByTagName('a');
}
```

divs will now be an array of the divs inside of your "elements" div. Links is now a two dimensional array, where the first index refers to the div inside your "elements" div, and the second index refers to the "a" tags inside that div.

`links[2][1]`

will refer to the element denoted below:

```
<div id="elements">
    <div>
        <a href="#">text</a>
        <a href="#">text</a>
        <a href="#">text</a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a href="#">text</a>
        <a href="#">text</a>
        <a href="#">text</a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a href="#">text</a>
        <a href="#">text</a>  //this one
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Or also, and I believe this is more accurately what you asked for:

> $("#elements div:eq(0) a:eq(1)")

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#elements a")

$("div a")

or $("a")
```

[**jQuery Selectors**](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)