# how to compile results of filter before rendered in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I've got a web app where the user's can enter 'rich text' content (tinymce) and have possibly entered hyperlinks. In my angular app, I'm rendering this in a div with ng-bind-html-unsafe to preserve all formatting. I would like to attach an 'ng-click' to any an all a hrefs in that content. I created a filter that parses the content and adds the 'ng-click' text to the resulting html. I interrogated the DOM and see the ng-click="alert('test')" but there's something I'm missing where the output from the filter isn't being "wired up" (compiled).

Comment: I think you need something akin to this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13405548/295797

Comment: Roy, thanks. I think the real answer is I need to be doing this in a directive, not a filter. That link you gave me gives me a good start. Thanks!

Comment: Same problem here, and I suspect you're right about having to use a directive, since using returning the result of $compile from a filter results in errors like `Uncaught Error: 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real answer is I needed to be doing this in a directive, not a filter. Roy's link https://stackoverflow.com/a/13405548/295797 provided the necessary guidance.
[answering own question to clear from 'unanswered' queue]