# AngularJS directives not showing in the source HTML

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a filter which turns hashtags into links:

```
app.filter('hashtags', function($filter) {
  return function(text, target) {
    if (!text) return text;
    var replacedText = text.replace(/#(\w*[a-zA-Z_]+\w*)/gim, '<a ng-href="/posts?q=%23$1">#$1</a>');
    return replacedText;
  };
});
```

However, when it is displayed on the page, the hashtag is clickable and surrounded in anchor tags, but the ng-href is no where to be found. It looks like this.

```
<a>#hashtag</a>
```

Why is the angular directive not showing up?

It may be worth noting that classes show up. If I were to change this line to read:

```
var replacedText = text.replace(/#(\w*[a-zA-Z_]+\w*)/gim, '<a class="test" ng-href="/posts?q=%23$1">#$1</a>');
```

The output in HTML would be:

```
<a class="test">#hashtag</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ng-href` would need to be pulled out of the filter and put into the template in which it is to be used.

```
<div ng-repeat="tag in tags">
    <a class="test" ng-href="{{tag | hashtag}}">{{tag}}</a>
</div>
```

The reason for this is that angular doesn't `$compile` when filtering.

See:

- [AngularJS + highlight.js (to evaluate string with expression in directive)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13385535/angularjs-highlight-js-to-evaluate-string-with-expression-in-directive/13405548#13405548)