# JavaScript to store jquery result set information in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

The project I am working has many of the same kind of element on a page. This kind of element contains some text that I need to store in an array. I can easily select all these elements with JQuery and have JQuery return a result set of elements. However, I am having a really difficult understanding how to iterate through all of the elements in the result set and storing the text from each element in an array.

I was thinking maybe using something like foreach somehow?

I appreciate any help in this regard.

Many thanks in advance!

HTML

```
<div class="option">apples</div>
<div class="option">oranges</div>
<div class="option">peaches</div>
<div class="option">grapes</div>
```

JavaScript

```
var i = 0;
foreach($('.option').text() as x){
    someArray[i] = x;
    i++;
}
```

Desired Output

```
alert(someArray[0]); // apples
alert(someArray[1]); // oranges
alert(someArray[2]); // peaches
alert(someArray[3]); // grapes
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get an array of list element contents in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247023/get-an-array-of-list-element-contents-in-jquery)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `$.each` to iterate over the elements.

```
var arr = [];
$('.option').each(function() {
    arr.push( $(this).text() );
});

console.log(arr.join());
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/RaHZ6/)**

You can also use the `.map` method

```
var arr = $('.option').map(function () {
    return this.innerHTML
}).get().join();

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `for`

```
var options = $('.option'),
newarray = [];

for (var i = 0, k = options.length; i < k; ++i){
    newarray[i] = options.eq(i).text(); 
}
console.log(newarray);
```

Probably good to know you can use `for` because it's similar to your first idea and you may need it when not including jQuery (of course the other jquery methods in my example wouldn't work in that case, but you get the idea).

http://jsfiddle.net/p7JWg/