# extract the content between <li></li> using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

i have a div,

```
 <div id="product-details">
      <li>lorem,ispum</li>
      <li>doler,emit</li>
      <li>emit,doler</li>
 </div>
```

I want to extract only the content between "li" into three variable. how it possible using jquery

Comment: Can you please share with us what methods you have tried? It looks like you're just asking us to do your work for you... It also appears that your HTML is somewhat invalid. You can't have `<li>` elements outside of a `<ul>` element.

Comment: here you go : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247023/get-an-array-of-list-element-contents-in-jquery

Answer (score 5):

The best method would be to extract the text into an array. To do this you can use a combination of `map()` and `text()`. Try this:

```
var liText = $('#product-details li').map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
}).get();
```

You can then retrieve the text from this array as you normally would, either via a loop, or direct access by index:

```
console.log(liText[1]); // = doler,emit
```

Comment: ... and also HTML structure is invalid.

Comment: @dfsq good point - I missed that. Possibly just an error in transcribing the question.