# How to get all dynamic ids arrey value to javascript VAR CID to find match in sql

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

In my php code I have dynamic php $id for each post like in my index.php page have `<div id=post'.$id.'>` display at browser console as

`<div id=post11>`

`<div id=post12>`

`<div id=post13>`

etc more else.

Now I want to sent my above post ids in my server.php file to make query by id **(if any id match in sql)** and those id will sent by Javascript `VAR CID = ''` from index.php page.

So my I want my javascript sent data like

```
VAR CID = 11 or 12 or 13 or anything else to match in sql;
```

And my server.php file get those id by

```
$_REQUEST['cid']= 11 or 12 or 13 or others more else to match in sql;
```

then make query to find if any id match in sql

```
WHERE id =".$_REQUEST['cid']." AND page_id=".$_REQUEST['tutid']." ORDER BY id DESC
```

Here is my related script:
Update script `(A server and Clint side regular update script)`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

var CID = ''; // Post id
var tutid = '<?php echo $pageid; ?>'; // Particular page id

function addrep(type, msg){
$("#newreply"+CID).append("");
}

function waitForRep(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "server.php",
        cache: false,
        data: "tutid="+ tutid + "&cid="+ CID,
        timeout:15000, 
        success: function(data){ 
            addrep("postreply", data);
                setTimeout(
                waitForRep, 
                15000 
            );
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
                setTimeout(
                waitForRep, 
                15000 
            );
        }
    });
};
$(document).ready(function(){
    waitForRep();
});
</script>
```

index.php

```
echo '<div id=post'.$id.'>name: AAAA </div>';
echo '<div id=post'.$id.'>name: BBBB </div>';
echo '<div id=post'.$id.'>name: CCCC </div>';
```

Server.php

```
while (true) {
   if($_REQUEST['tutid'] && $_REQUEST['cid']){

   // make query by $tutid and $cid

   }
}
```

Comment: Here's a link that can explain how to do it:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247023/get-an-array-of-list-element-contents-in-jquery

Comment: @Yair.R how to get ids from here: `<div id=post'.$id.'>` by `var arr = $("yourdivid").map(function() { return $(this).text() }).get();`

Comment: return $(this).attr('id').slice(5)

Comment: Sorry I read about this before but, I can't do it. .

Comment: update above, my script is a server and Clint side regular update script. so no need to click or others else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `data-post-id="'.$id.'"` attribute do the DIV's in *Index.php* (so that you don't have to extract the ID's from `id` attribute):

```
echo '<div data-post-id="'.$id.'" id=post'.$id.'>name: '.$name.' say: Detail: '.$datail.' </div>';
```

Script:

```
var tutid = '<?php echo $pageid; ?>'; // Particular page id

// --- to get all ID's as array: --- //
var CID = [];
$('div[data-post-id]').each(function(i){
    CID[i] = $(this).data('post-id');
});

// --- to get single ID: --- //
// var CID = $('div[data-post-id]').data('post-id');

function addrep(type, msg){
    // --- if CID is an array, this ain't gonna work: --- //
    //$("#newreply"+CID).append("");

    // --- you need to loop through the CID array: --- //
    CID.forEach(function(id){
        $("#newreply"+id).append("");
    });
}

function waitForRep(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "server.php",
        cache: false,
        data: {
            tutid : tutid,
            // this way array containing all ID's can be sent:
            cid : CID
        },
        timeout:15000, 
        success: function(data){ 
            addrep("postreply", data);
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
        }
    });
};
```

Then in *server.php*:

```
// need to loop through the $_GET['cid'], as it's an array sent over AJAX:
foreach($_GET['cid'] as $key => $value){
    // do something with $value ...
}
```

Comment: Thank u sir. May be I can't described well. I want my server.php query get data where $cid= 10 or 12 or 13. If he found any data with any cid than he can do echo. Your code's `var CID = [];........CID[i] = $(this).data('post-id');
});` get only my 1st id And if i use `var CID = $('div[data-post-id]').data('post-id');` its do tothing.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get your point. You may need to show your `server.php` code. And a more of `index.php` (at least what is the **newreply+ID** element)

Comment: Sir. Array only get 1st post id, but I accept your ans because it give me a big guideline.