# How can i obtain all download links in HTML and store them in a array using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Hi there i am relatively new to javascript and i have been attempting to store hyperlinks with the `<a>` tag into a array in javascript is there a elegant or simple way of doing this?

Comment: What you want is certainly do-able, but you're going to need to explain what you mean by, "hyperlinks with the tag." Moreover, showing a sample of your HTML and the JavaScript you've tried so far is a must.

Comment: You'll probably have to add some code along with a few examples of things you tried in order to receive any help. You can always update your question. Welcome to stack overflow, recommended reading: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: [`document.links`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Document/links)

Comment: I am not too sure how to word it. i just wish to search a site find all the download links that are there and display them. So i assumed you would have to search through the HTML code to find all the anchor tags "<a>".

Comment: @Dr.Molle — interesting... in Chrome developer tools just now, on _this_ page, `document.links` produced `HTMLCollection[199]` while `document.getElementsByTagName('a')` produced `HTMLCollection[215]` ... because some `<a>` tags could be `<a name="...">` and **not** `<a href="...">`

Comment: @Matthew A link is a link ... what is a _"download link"?_ Only links to downloadable files, as opposed to links to other web pages?  If that's it, how would you tell the difference?  Also keep in mind that not all `<a>` tags are links of any kind.

Comment: anchor tags aren't always links ... sometimes they are just placeholders. See this question: [Is an anchor tag without the href attribute safe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292343/is-an-anchor-tag-without-the-href-attribute-safe)

Comment: also note that `document.links` also includes `<area href/>` , to get only the `<a hrefs>` you may use `document.querySelectorAll('a[href]')`

Answer (score 1):

Hi you have this response:
[Get an array of list element contents in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247023/get-an-array-of-list-element-contents-in-jquery)

You only need change

```
var links = [];
$("a").each(function() { links.push($(this).attr('href')) });
```

If you dont want to use jquery, nice!

You can do

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('a'),
    links = [];
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
   links.push(elements[i].getAttribute('href'));
}
```

Comment: I believe in your first snippet you meant to use links instead of optionTexts, as optionTexts is not defined anywhere.