# Setting variable for input value shows object object message

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

I have a list of properties of which each has a reference number and I am trying to separate each reference by a comma then set them for a input field value, I am unsure if its the correct way to do it, however I am receiving a [object Object] message, my code is:

```
var propertyRef = $( ".reference" ).clone().append(',').contents();
$('#propertyRef').val(propertyRef);
```

Comment: I think this will solve your problem
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247023/get-an-array-of-list-element-contents-in-jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247023/get-an-array-of-list-element-contents-in-jquery)

Comment: Thanks for that but now its not setting it as the value of the field my code to to this:


`var propertyRefs = [];
  $(".reference").each(function() {
   propertyRefs.push($(this).text())
  });
  var propertyRef = "Shortlist: " + propertyRefs.join(', ');
  
  console.log(propertyRef);
  
  //$propertyRef.appendTo('#propertyRef');`


although the code seems a lot better than what i had :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, try this code:

```
<ul id="list">
    <li>10</li>
    <li>20</li>
    <li>30</li>
</ul>
<input type="text" id="input" />
<input type="button" value=Convert" onclick="convertList2String()" />

<script>
function convertList2String() {
    var id_list = [];
    $("#list li").each(function() {
        id_list.push($(this).text());
    });
    var id_list_str = '"' + id_list.join('", "') + '"';
    $('#input').val(id_list_str);
}
</script>
```

**UPDATE:**
if you do not want to quote the id, then use this line instead:

```
var id_list_str = id_list.join(',');
```

Comment: That worked, I changed your code to match mine:

`var propertyRefs = [];
  $(".reference").each(function() {
   propertyRefs.push($(this).text())
  });
  var propertyRef = "Shortlist: " + propertyRefs.join(', ');
  
  console.log(propertyRef);
  
  $('#propertyRef').val(propertyRef);`

and it works great, thanks :)