# How to filter a list of options using a list of possible values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking to filter a list of options from a select input and remount the filtered list.

The backend will send over the array of options values that are to be filtered which match to those in the list.

I'm not sure if `options` is the best attribute to use? (

```
var initial_options = $('select_id').options
```

The options are of the form eg

```
 [
    '<option value="" selected="">Option 0</option>', 
    '<option value="1">Option 1</option>'],
    ...
 ]
```

the returned data to be used for filtering is of the form

```
var option_values_filter = [1,3,5,6]
```

then mounted with:

```
$('#select_id').html(filtered_options)
```

Comment: So the output from the server is `['<option value="" selected="">Option 0</option>', <option value="1">Option 1</option>']`? What is `var option_values_filter = [1,3,5,6]`? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Do you mean that you need to compare each value in the option_values_filter to the html tags and render only those which match?

Comment: Yes sorry I'm comparing the option values to the values returned from the backend ie just an array of ints.  each int is meant to represent an option value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your values filter is attempting to filter on the actual `value` option property you can try something like this:

```js
const option_values_filter = [1, 3, 4];

const filtered = $("#id option").filter((index, option) => {
  return (option_values_filter.indexOf(parseInt(option.value)) !== -1);
});

$(id).html(filtered);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="id">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

Here is a pure javascript solution:

```js
const option_values_filter = [1, 3, 4];

const selectElement = document.getElementById("id");
const newOptions = Array.apply(null, selectElement.options).filter((option) => {
 return option_values_filter.indexOf(parseInt(option.value)) !== -1;
}).map(option => option.outerHTML);

selectElement.innerHTML = newOptions;
```

```html
<select id="id">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer in combination with your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48230976/4760460). Using pure javascript.

```js
var selectBoxEl = document.getElementById('selectBox');
var arrayOfNodes = selectBoxEl.childNodes;
var optionsArr = [];
var filteredArr = [];

var option_values_filter = [1, 3, 5, 6]

// loop through child nodes of select box and store option nodes as a string in array
for (var i = 0; i < arrayOfNodes.length; i++) {
  if (arrayOfNodes[i].nodeName === 'OPTION') {
    optionsArr.push(arrayOfNodes[i].outerHTML);
  }
}

// function to filter options array and set select box options to filtered array
function filterOptions(filterOps) {
  console.log(optionsArr[0].indexOf('value="'));
  var val;
  for (var i = 0; i < optionsArr.length; i++) { 
    val = optionsArr[i].substring(optionsArr[i].indexOf('value="') + 7, optionsArr[i].indexOf('value="') + 8);
    if (filterOps.indexOf(parseInt(val)) !== -1) {
      filteredArr.push(optionsArr[i]);
    }
  }
  selectBoxEl.innerHTML = filteredArr;
}

filterOptions(option_values_filter);
```

```html
<select id="selectBox">
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="3">Option 3</option>
  <option value="4">Option 4</option>
</select>
```